# Как изменить позиционирование каретки в Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, chart.js

комьюнити! У меня возникла проблема с tooltips элементом в Chart.js. Работаю с версией 2.9.3.

Проблема заключается в том, что все каретки позиционируются относительно центра (и стремятся к нему), однако для моего случая это не требуется. Нужно, чтобы каретки стремились к оси X, чтобы их позиции были или снизу о точки, или сверху.

Как я могу решить такую проблему?
(Код не требуется, так как это работа с глобалкой)